# Characters on page coming out as question marks, despite charset="utf-8"

Tags: html, character-encoding

Someone was kind enough to do a Czech translation for our website, but the special characters come out as questions marks, example:

[image]

This is the text meant to be showing in the black bar:

> Internet Explorer a Safari by mìli podporovat Ogg Vorbis audio. Dejme jim to na vìdomí!

The page is HTML5, and here is the header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="cs">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css" />    
    <meta name="description" content="HTML5 audio is a bit of a mess.  It would be easiest if Internet Explorer and Safari supported the high quality Ogg Vorbis format which would be free for everyone to use." />
    <link href="http://www.wewantogg.com" rel="canonical" />
    <title>Ogg Vorbis Support for Internet Explorer and Safari</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quattrocento+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>

<body>
```

We are using a google web font, but I tried changing it to Arial but no luck, still lots of question marks.  I was under the assumption the UTF-8 should allow me to use special chars?

Comment: The meta tag will be ignored unless you have `AddDefaultCharset Off` in your **.htaccess* file for Apache.  Or equiv.  You could put a `AddCharset UTF-8 .html` in there, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try

`<meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />`

Comment: As far as I know, `ISO-8859-1` stores the characters you need and `utf-8` doesn't.  Not much of an explanation!

Comment: Because what you have in your page isn't encoded in UTF-8. And UTF-8 can represent *any* code point, unlike Latin-1, which is targeted at *Western* Europe.

Comment: I found that I also had to save the actual ASP file as UTF8 as well otherwise none of my sql statements returned the right data.

Answer (score 4):

You should go with UTF-8, not ISO-8859-1.

Did you look at your database tables and db connection settings? You Table Collation should be set to `utf8_general_ci`, and when you establish your connection you must run a `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` right after you're connected.
Also, make sure your http-header set to

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

on your webserver.

(Edit: this applies to php/mysql; not sure what system you are running...)

Answer (score 1):

You can try

also you can try it on javascript tag like this

```
<script src="test.js" charset="iso-8859-1"></script>
```

to fix the  questions marks charset error on any javascript popups